# My windows XP 2 is not starting up as DEP has blocked everything. Help Me

Tags: windows, dep

As i have a demo of my project And my data is inside my system and the DEP has blocked everything on my system please help me to rectify the problem ASAP.

I only see my wallpaper and nothing else, what can I do?

Comment: Convert your PowerPoint slides into bitmaps and change the wallpaper as a way to display the presentation.

Comment: Mann please help me out.. Dont joke with right now.. Please I am in deep trouble... please tell me what to do to change the settings of DEP in my system

Comment: @taspeotis, I want so badly to vote up your comment but it's not Slashdot. Luckily you've posted an answer which I've voted up instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Boot into Safe Mode and then [disable DEP](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/566/xp-sp2-how-to-turn-off-the-data-execution-prevention-feature-dep/).